# Closed question via 5th vote, but incorrect close reason won 3-2

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I recently voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893049/how-to-implement-email-verification-with-javascript), which I believe was the right thing to do.  However, I closed as "too broad", while it was marked as closed as "duplicate" with a question that is clearly not a duplicate.

What should I have done in this case?  I could've known in advance that the wrong close reason would be chosen, since it showed 3 votes for duplicate and only one for too broad when I went to close it.  But not closing it doesn't seem right, either, since it doesn't fit SO.

In the absence of a better action to take, I would like to tentatively suggest that a given close reason needs to attain a certain number of votes rather than all close reasons combined.

Edit: I did flag for moderator attention, but that feels like a last resort that shouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: *"a given close reason needs to attain a certain number of votes"* - so then if the community is very split on the reason, you could potentially have dozens of votes spread around but the question still open? When everyone agrees it should be closed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, that's why I said "tentatively" - but would we really prefer to prematurely give a poor close reason rather than wait until there's proper consensus?

Comment: Taking this to an extreme if a reason needs x votes to close then it could take `x * number of close reasons` close votes to close a question.

Comment: @NathanOliver wouldn't it be [(x-1)*number of close reasons] +1?  (VERY pedantic point I agree :P)

Comment: @Patrice You are correct.  *bows before supreme mathematical talents* ;)

Comment: If you really want to have it re-opened and closed again for the correct reason, feel free to drop a request in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: @rene I can do that (in much the same way I could and did flag for mod attention), but I still don't think that is a good answer to "what should I have done" or "how can we prevent this situation".

Comment: SOCVR re-opened/closed to remove the bad duplicate mark, so I guess this is taken care of.  Still a bit curious about how I could've avoided the fuss, though.

Comment: This is why we should remove the names from the headline of "put on hold as X" and move them to after each reason explanation, like signatures. I hate seeing "this question was put on hold as too broad by A, B, C, D, and TylerH" when I cast a different CV. It's mis-attribution.

Answer (score 3):

In the current state of the features available to us mortals you have done every thing you could:

- Already one user informed the duplicate voter that it was the wrong dupe.
- You left a comment with a better close voting advice
- After it was closed incorrectly you came to meta to seek assistance
- Some evil chat room acted as a re-open/close vote mob
- For extra assurance you flagged for a moderator.

I think only the last step is kind of pointless, and I expect that flag will be declined.

If that chat room didn't interfere, the question should have been edited to make clear that the duplicate was wrong and to make it less of a tool request, broad topic. That would have sent it to the re-open queue.

I see enough questions that are so far down on the quality bar that close voters can pick any possible close reasons and it still fits, and that includes possible duplicates. From my handling of the CVQ I can assure you that this happens a lot.

I don't think more than 5 votes should be needed to close a question. As long as we agree that a question needs to be closed, it is fine. Only in cases of blatantly wrong duplicates on questions that are worth keeping (I'm not convinced this is true for your example) should we go down the re-open/close-vote correctly route. Re-open votes and close-votes are expensive; the users that are using them have not enough of them to keep the site free of <s>crap</s> low quality posts.

What would be nice is a proper attribution for each voter. You can support this [MSE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason) from 2010. Given the 6 to 8 years planning, expect this to be live not earlier than next year.

Comment: "some evil chat room" I can think of one in particular...

Comment: Thanks for the big write-up.  I think that feature request from 2010 would solve much of my problem, which was that I was associated with a clearly wrong close reason.  I see why you wouldn't want to increase the number of necessary close votes and no longer think that would be a good solution.  In the future I'll probably skip the chat room/moderator flag and just communicate to the asker what the problem was.

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks for the feedback and please keep close voting despite the wrong attribution now and then, we need every close vote ..